# Shading on model is not smooth in some places

Tags: shaders

I created this face in blender, it has smooth shading on but shadows in some areas appear sharp, I want the shadows to appear smooth consistently. Here's an example of the issue i'm having:

[image: Image of Shading issues]

I'm not sure what i've done wrong, I'll happily supply the .blend file or any other additional information if needed upon request, Thanks! :D

Comment: First thing i would do is check for double vertices and try recalculating normals (CTR+N)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Johan, but I have recalculated the normals and checked for any doubles but that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're most likely experiencing is cycles not being able to shade properly on such a lowpoly mesh.

Some things that could fix this are:

- Adding a Subsurf modifier to your mesh can smooth it out and remove some artifacting.
- Having Auto Smooth in `Data >> Normals` unticked or set to 180 can remove unwanted sharp edges.
- Increasing the size of you **sun** lamp also smooths out the shading.

Comment: Thank you, this does appear to be what the issue was, I ended up just adding extra geometry to the areas with shading defects and that worked perfectly thank you!